# Divide string to assoc array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:

```
$config = 'app.name = "My App";
            app.id = "myappid";
            app.components.cache.id = "Memcache";';
```

I need to convert it to array like this:

```
app=>[
    'name=>'My App',
    'id'=>'myappid',
    'components'=>[
        'cache'=>['id'=>'Memcache']
    ]
]
```

I use explode for divide on the pieces, but i don't know what i need to do next.

```
$arr = explode(";", $config);
$data = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $pieces = explode('=', $item);
    $pieces_dotes = explode('.', $pieces[0]);
    foreach ($pieces_dotes as $piece) {
     //what i need to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Within the inner `foreach` loop, you're assigning the temp variable by reference to itself, so you build a stack of array keys, and then assign the value to it at the end.

```
$config = 'app.name = "My App";
            app.id = "myappid";
            app.components.cache.id = "Memcache";';
$arr = explode(";", $config);
$data = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $temp = &$data;
    $item = trim($item);
    if (empty($item)) continue;
    list($setting, $value) = explode("=", trim($item));
    $setting = explode(".", trim($setting));
    foreach ($setting as $set) {
        $temp = &$temp[$set];
    }
    $temp = trim($value, '" ');
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by building the array levels based on the key and keeping a reference to the last added level in the array. My solution (based on what you already had) is as follows:

```
<?php

$config = 'app.name = "My App";
           app.id = "myappid";
           app.components.cache.id = "Memcache";';

$arr = explode(";", $config);
$data = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $pieces = explode('=', $item);
    $currentValue = trim(str_replace('"', '', $pieces[1]));
    $pieces_dotes = explode('.', $pieces[0]);

    // Set initial value of $currentLevel to root of data array
    $currentLevel = &$data;

    // Initiate count & iterator vars
    $numPieces = count($pieces_dotes);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($pieces_dotes as $piece) {
        // Increment $i and set $newKey to be trimmed version of current piece of the dot notated level
        $i++;
        $newKey = trim($piece);

        // Skip empty $newKey
        if(empty($newKey)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Assign the $currentValue once we are at the required depth
        if($i == $numPieces) {
            $currentLevel[$newKey] = $currentValue;
        }

        // We are not at the required depth yet so initiate the key as an array if required
        if(empty($currentLevel[$newKey])) {
            $currentLevel[$newKey] = [];
        }

        // Set the $currentLevel to reference the new key
        if(is_array($currentLevel[$newKey])) {
            $currentLevel = &$currentLevel[$newKey];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution using custom recursive function `fillBypath`:

```
/**
 * Fills an array by hierarchical 'key path'
 * 
 * @param type $value value in each 'key path'
 * @param type $keys hierarchical key list
 * @param type $arr the resulting array(passed by reference)
 */
function fillByPath($value, $keys, &$arr) {  
    $c = count($keys) - 1;

    foreach ($keys as $idx => $k) {
        if ($idx == $c) {     // check if it's the last key in the "key path"
            $arr[$k] = $value;
            break;
        }

        if (isset($arr[$k]) && is_array($arr[$k])) {
            fillByPath($value, array_slice($keys, $idx + 1), $arr[$k]);
            break;
        } else {
            $arr[$k] = [];
            fillByPath($value, array_slice($keys, $idx + 1), $arr[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

$config = 'app.name = "My App";
            app.id = "myappid";
            app.components.cache.id = "Memcache";';

$result = [];
foreach (array_filter(explode(";", $config)) as $path) {
    list($keyPath, $v) = explode(" = ", trim($path));
    $keys = explode(".", $keyPath);  // getting key list
    fillByPath($v, $keys, $result);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [name] => "My App"
            [id] => "myappid"
            [components] => Array
                (
                    [cache] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => "Memcache"
                        )
                )
        )
)
```